# How to bind data on client side pagination on kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Actual we have one scenario to update data source on client side pagination. Is it possible on kendo grid ? or we should take approach to update kendo grid element.

Comment: are u trying do like server side paging, getting updated data from server ?

Comment: when you need to change the data source?? can you pls describe the exact scenario??